# How to provide your services via @Context in Neo4j unmanaged extension

Tags: java, neo4j

I have Neo4j unmanaged extension. I want some services to be created as singletons and be available via `@Context` in my resources.

Something like this:

```
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleResource {

    public ExampleResource(@Context CostlyService costlyService) { // <<---
        // use it here
    }
}
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j has [PluginLifecycle](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/server/plugins/PluginLifecycle.html) interface that give us possibility to hook into Neo4j server lifecycle and provide our own services for injection [blog post](http://vrublevsky.me/neo4j/java/how-to-provide-your-services-via-context-in-neo4j-unmanaged-extension.html).

So, we have service. Let's take this one as example:

```
public interface CostlyService {
}

public class CostlyServiceImpl implements CostlyService {

    public CostlyService() {
        // a LOT of work done here
    }

    //...
}
```

Now we need to make our own `PluginLifecycle` implementation:

```
public class ExamplePluginLifecycle implements PluginLifecycle {

    @Override
    public Collection<Injectable<?>> start(GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService,
                                           Configuration config) {
        final List<Injectable<?>> injectables = new ArrayList<>();
        return injectables;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }
}
```

As you see, injectable list is empty for now. We will add our service there soon.

**Important:** you must register your `PluginLifecycle` implementation, so it will be available via SPI:

```
// file: META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLifecycle
my.company.extension.ExamplePluginLifecycle
```

This will make your `PluginLifecycle` discoverable by Neo4j server.

Now we need to create actual injectable. Let's write implementation for `Injectable` interface:

```
public final class TypedInjectable<T> implements Injectable<T> {

    private final T value;
    private final Class<T> type;

    private TypedInjectable(final T value, final Class<T> type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static <T> TypedInjectable<T> injectable(final T value, final Class<T> type) {
        return new TypedInjectable<>(value, type);
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

This will serve as simple container for our service. Usage:

```
import static my.company.extension.TypedInjectable.injectable;

injectable(new CostlyServiceImpl(), CostlyService.class);
```

Now we can add our injectable into `PluginLifecycle`.

```
@Override
public Collection<Injectable<?>> start(GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService,
                                       Configuration config) {
    final List<Injectable<?>> injectables = new ArrayList<>();
    injectables.add(injectable(new CostlyServiceImpl, CostlyService.class)); // <<---
    return injectables;
}
```

After this change our CostlyService will be available for our resources via @Context:

```
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleResource {

    public ExampleResource(@Context CostlyService costlyService) {
        // use it here
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Tip**: keep your PluginLifecycle's in same package or in subpackage with your resources.