# How to inject object into Context in Jersey 2.x

Tags: java, neo4j, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I was trying to inject providers and use `@Context` to use the object in neo4j and Jersey 2.x. For now, I implement it by self-defined annotation such as:

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BaseInject {}
```

and provider as:

```
@Singleton
public class BaseExecutorResolver implements InjectionResolver<BaseInject> {

private Database database;   

@Override
public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> serviceHandle) {

    if (Database.class == injectee.getRequiredType()) {
        database = Neo4jContainer.neo4jServer.getDatabase();
        return database;
    }
    return null;

}
@Override
public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isMethodParameterIndicator() {
    return true;
}
}
```

the binding code are as follows:

```
bind(BaseExecutorResolver.class).to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<BaseInject>>() {
            }).in(Singleton.class);
```

In the resource class, I can use `@BaseInject Database db` to get the inject objects.

But if I want to get the inject object by use `@Context`, how should I modify the code here?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the InjectionResolver is as follows:   
public class BaseExecutorResolver implements InjectionResolver<BaseInject> {
    private Database database;   
    @Override
    public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> serviceHandle) {
        if (Database.class == injectee.getRequiredType()) {
            database = Neo4jContainer.neo4jServer.getDatabase();
            return database;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Comment: What you want is a `Factory` as seen [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) for Neo4j here is [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624603/how-to-provide-your-services-via-context-in-neo4j-unmanaged-extension) on how to "provide your services via @Context in Neo4j unmanaged extension".

#### Quick outline

Neo4j has `PluginLifecycle`. You can implement your own and provide `injectables` there.

Code example:

```
public class ExamplePluginLifecycle implements PluginLifecycle {

    @Override
    public Collection<Injectable<?>> start(GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService,
                                           Configuration config) {
        final List<Injectable<?>> injectables = new ArrayList<>();
        injectables.add(injectable(new CostlyServiceImpl, CostlyService.class)); // <---
        return injectables;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }
}
```